# Scipy Stats rv_continuous without normalization constant

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, bayesian

I want to draw random deviates from a distribution where I don't know the normalizing constant. The distribution is the conjugate prior of the gamma likelihood with unknown shape and scale=1.  The pdf is given on wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions as

[image]

There is no closed form for the integral of this pdf. Is using scipy.stats.rv_continuous an option here? If not, what else can anyone recommend for drawing deviates from an arbitrary pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the normalization integral numerically (`scipy.integrate.quad`) is always an option.

Comment: Thanks for that tip!  Little worried about the speed of that.  According to wikipedia it's actually not necessary to know the normalizing constant to sample using some algorithms. I would imagine that avoiding calculating an integral numerically would be faster.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

Comment: Yes, that's an option too :-). You'll need a good majorant though.